# I am unable to fetch excel data to selenium code At ubuntu o/s

Tags: excel, selenium

```
public class ReadAndWrite {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException 
{
    System.out.println("hello");
    ReadAndWrite.login();
}
public static void login() throws BiffException, IOException, InterruptedException{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("URL");
    System.out.println("hello");

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("/home/sagarpatra/Desktop/Xpath.ods");
    System.out.println("hiiiiiii");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet sh = w.getSheet(1); 
    //or w.getSheet(Sheetnumber)
    //String variable1 = s.getCell(column, row).getContents();

    for(int row=1; row <=sh.getRows();row++)
    {
    String username = sh.getCell(0, row).getContents();
    System.out.println("Username "+username);
    driver.get("URL");
    driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys(username);
    String password= sh.getCell(1, row).getContents();
    System.out.println("Password "+password);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys(password);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Login")).click();
     System.out.println("Waiting for page to load fully...");
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    }
    driver.quit();
    }

}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code, or how to fix it. It outputs the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
at test.ReadTest.main(ReadTest.java:19)
```

Comment: Biff Exception usually comes when The excel sheet is not saved in proper manner. Try saving your excel in `2003-2007` format

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [Apache MetaModel](http://metamodel.incubator.apache.org/) instead.  I have had better luck with that, than using JXL.  [Here is a example project I wrote](https://github.com/djangofan/MetaModelExample) that reads from a .XLSX file.  I use this library to run tests on a Linux Jenkins server from .XLS files generated on MS Windows.

Also, it should be noted that this library is also perfect for making a parameterized DataProvider that queries a database with JDBC.

Using JXL, you limit yourself to one data type, either .XLS or .CSV.  I believe MetaModel is actually using JXL under the hood and wrapping it to make it easier to use.  So, it also would support the OpenOffice documents in the same fashion and suffer the same file compatibility issues.